# Have US Officials ever commented on the results of foreign elections?

Tags: united-states, election, international-relations

I was flipping through the news channels this morning, so I cannot be certain which channel it was, but I believe an anchor on MSNBC made it a point to note that several foreign  officials commented negatively on the election of Trump, and quoted a few.

Has the reverse ever occurred?  Has a US Official, elected or otherwise, ever publicly commented about a validly elected *candidate* in a foreign election?  I mean in a statement that went beyond a generic congratulations or assurance that we would work closely with the newly elected.

Something along the lines of British Labor party leader Jeremy Corbin's [lamentations](http://www.foxnews.com/world/2016/11/09/many-british-politicians-react-with-anger-to-trumps-victory.html#)

Comment: Why do you change the entire goal of your question after you have received a popular answer? Would it be better to revert your edits and ask a new question?

Comment: @Qsigma  Because the "popular" answer was not "popular" when I edited the question for clarity and because it did not answer the question I had asked which was admittedly poorly phrased..  Please also note that I added a comment to curiousdannii 's question within minutes indicating this.

Comment: In my opinion, it did not answer the question you had in your head. It does answer the question you asked, and I believe that your original question, your new question, and curiousdanni's answer all deserve upvotes and add to the site. Please ask a new question and I will upvote it, even though I am slightly puzzled by the Jeremy Corbyn comparison: he his Leader of the Opposition and an MP, so not really an official.  I disagree with curiousdanni's request that you edit your question.

Answer (score 9):

Many times. Here's just a few:

- [Obama on the 2010 Myanmar election:](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2010/nov/08/burma-election-voter-intimidation)

  > "When peaceful democratic movements are suppressed - as in Burma - then the democracies of the world cannot remain silent. For it is unacceptable to gun down peaceful protestors and incarcerate political presoners decade after decade. It is unacceptable to hold the aspirations of an entire people hostage to the greed and paranoia of a bankrupt regime. It is unacceptable to steal an election as the regime has done again for all the world to see"
- [On the 2013 election of Mugabe:](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-africa-23563029)

  > The US state department also called for an investigation and said the results were not a "credible expression of the will of the Zimbabwean people".
- [On the 2014 Syrian election:](http://www.state.gov/r/pa/prs/dpb/2014/06/227073.htm#SYRIA)

  > Two more toppers, the first on Syria: Today’s presidential election in Syria is a disgrace. Bashar al-Assad has no more credibility today than he did yesterday. Elections should be an opportunity for the people of a free society to be consulted and to play an important role in choosing their leaders. Instead, such a process was inconceivable today in Syria, where the regime continued to reject the courageous calls for freedom and dignity that started more than three years ago. It intentionally denied millions of Syrians the right to vote and continued to massacre the very electorate it purports to represent and protect. Just today, we also note reports the regime shelled the Yarmouk refugee camp and eastern Ghouta.
  >
  > Detached from reality and devoid of political participation, the Assad regime-staged election today continues a 40-year family legacy of violent suppression that brutally crushes political dissent and fails to fulfill Syrians’ aspirations for peace and prosperity.
- [The US, UK and Norway issued a joint statement on the 2015 Sudanese election:](http://www.state.gov/r/pa/prs/ps/2015/04/240887.htm)

  > The members of the Troika (Norway, the United Kingdom, and the United States) regret the Government of Sudan’s failure to create a free, fair, and conducive elections environment. Restrictions on political rights and freedoms, counter to the rights enshrined in the Sudanese Constitution, the lack of a credible national dialogue, and the continuation of armed conflict in Sudan’s peripheries, are among the reasons for the reported low participation and very low voter turnout. The outcome of these elections cannot be considered a credible expression of the will of the Sudanese people.
  >
  > We condemn the acts of violence during the election period and continue to support those Sudanese who wish to peacefully advance a comprehensive and legitimate political process of dialogue, toward an end to the conflict, meaningful governance reform, and long-term stability.

For more, take a look through Wikipedia's [List of controversial elections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_controversial_elections).

Comment: Those comments are more about the electoral *process* than about the elected candidate.

Comment: Thanks.  I will take a look at the link you provided, but these comments are not quite the same.  They all appear to be commenting on the validity of the election itself and not on the positive or negative effects of  a _validly_ elected individual.

Comment: @MichaelJ But that's what the question was asking about. "Has a US Official, elected or otherwise, ever publicly commented on the election results in a foreign nation?" These are all comments on the election results, namely that the US officials think the results were obtained through corruption. If that's not what you meant then please edit your question to explain exactly what you mean.

Comment: @curiousdannii  You are correct.  The meaning of question was perfectly obvious to me, but I wrote it.  I'll reword it shortly

Comment: Obama's political team, and maybe US taxpayer money, was used to try to influence the last Israeli election.  Might interest you.

Comment: @curiousdannii They think the results were obtained by corruption because they think (maybe correctly, it's irrelevant) that the person who was elected is someone who would use such methods or who would not have gotten in without doing so.

Comment: @KDog - that's completely false.